# Where is the EventListener stored?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, dom, addeventlistener

HHi everybody.
Anybody know where are stored Event when we use addEventListener method ???
example :

```
window.addEventListener('mousedown', this.myvar.onClick );
```

that's ok , but i try to find where it's stored ???
i try check in

```
windows.event
windows.Event()
console.dir(window.addEventListener)
window._debugWindow
window.dispatchEvent()
// ... many other try
```

I found no way to check where currents data listener stored.
[image]

i need to have the list || register for debug
thank for help

SOLVED EDIT:
[image]

Comment: If you log window.event inside your eventListener mousedown should be listed under type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Chrome's devtools, you can use `getEventListeners(node)` to view what is bound on an object.

Comment: yep i know multi way to use it, but where are the register ? for managing and debug ?

Comment: thank you so mutch it work and also i think i can find in Element and events listener tabs